Remove UAC from Print Server Properties
Which permissions should I set to be able to edit Print Server Properties without having to click on the UAC button?

Additional information (update 2024-10-02):
I have this problem with a printer driver from Seagull (cab SQUIX 4.3/300P) where I would like to retrieve the resident fonts (fonts installed on the printer). This works on the test server but it doesn't on the production server, which results in labels being printed wrong. I asked a question on the Seagull forum and was told it probably had to do with permissions. Now I'm trying to get these permissions fixed.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It requires elevated permissions which is only possible with the UAC prompt

@Ramhound I've updated the question to give more context.

You are using a roundabout way to access the printer properties dialog. Try opening it directly, setting printer properties does not require admin rights. // The printer’s ACLs are on the “Security” tab.

@GuidoNeele - I appreciate the additional information but it does not change the fact, the action you are attempting to do, will still require elevated permissions which an only be accomplished with a UAC prompt. Even if UAC is disable, user action to elevate the permissions is still required, this has been the case since Windows 7. It's even more true in 2024 and modern versions of Windows Server and Windows.

Turned out this problem indeed had to do with permissions but it had to do with being able to install untrusted fonts. The printer driver wanted to install untrusted fonts on the machine and group policy prevented that from happening. As a result the resident fonts didn't show up.
